# Counterproductive - 起到反作用 - how to parse?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I learned that in Chinese **counterproductive** is **起到反作用** or **起反作用**

I'm trying to figure out what the characters or words mean in this phrase.

I know 作用 means *result* or *effect* here, 反 means *opposite*. How does 起 fit in here and what part of speech is it? Is 到 necessary, or is it a completed action marker here?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

起 = establish

作用 = effect

起作用 = take effect

反(opposite) --> (opposite of positive = negative)

**起反作用** = take opposite (negative) effect  --> The opposite result of the intended goal = **counterproductive**

When your action cause a positive/productive effect, that is 起(正面)作用

When your action cause a negative/ counterproductive, effect, that is 起反面作用 = 起反作用

正面 in 起正面作用 is omitted because the term 'effect' is presumed positive.

Example:

突襲起了作用 -- The raid took effect (a positive effect/ result of improving the odds of winning)

突襲起了反作用 -- The raid took opposite effect (a negative effect/ result of worsening the odds of winning)

'到' in '起到作用' is a verb particle that indicates the verb is succefully completed

Comment: Great, makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can see it nicely here:

作为回应采取了一些措施，
Some measures adopted in response,
比如限制出口，
such as export restrictions,
起到了强烈的反作用。
led to (a) strong counter-effect. = have been highly counterproductive.

起到： give rise to
反作用： opposite, counter-effect

Comment: Thanks, the example helped.